# Вывод всех записей кроме последней добавленой getResources MODX Revo

Tags: modx

Есть вывод getResources который выводит 4 записи:

```
  [[!getResources?
  &elementClass=`modSnippet`
  &showHidden=`1`
  &tpl=`T_first_event`
  &limit=`4`
  &includeContent=`1`
  &includeTVs=`1`
  &depth=`1`
  &parents=`[[*id]]`
  &hideContainers=`1`
  ]]
```

Как вивести все записи кроме последней добавленой?

Answer (score 1):

Легко - отсортируй по дате добавления и укажи сдвиг:

```
&sortby=`{"publishedon":"DESC"}`
&offset=`1`
```